# Strange SFINAE code

Tags: c++, sfinae

I found this code in conjunction to SFINAE:

```
template<int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template<int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected  when I is odd
}
```

How does it work? It looks like an unnamed parameter array but I don't understand how the subscripting helps in overload resolution.

Answer (score 7):

Array bounds in C++ cannot be zero. If the expression (e.g., `I % 2 == 0`) is `false`, that's converted to zero, resulting in an invalid type and therefore substitution failure.

Essentially, it's an obfuscated version of `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember this is called like this: `div<1234>()` => first overload is called.

To understand you only need to look at the argument:

`char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0`
This means it is pointer to an array of chars. This array has the default value 0. This means you could also do `char a[] = "hello world"; div<1234>(a);`

`I % 2 == 0` is evaluated at compile time. You should know what it does. Even integers make this true, Odd integers make this false. True evaluates to 1, false evaluates to 0. However there is no such thing as an array with zero elements. This is what you call a SFINAE error. It doesn't mean it is a fundamental error, just that the blanks in the template could not be substituted adequately. *The template doesn't match*.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by T.C. since you cannot have arrays of 0 element, when the condition is false, the boolean `false` is converted to 0: the type becomes char (*)[0] (pointer to a char array of size 0) and this triggers SFINAE.

Now, in a more conventional (and readable) way, you would usually let `std::enable_if` do the job:

```
template <int I, std::enable_if_t<I%2>* = nullptr>
div() {
    std::cout << "I (" << I <<") am odd." << std::endl;
}

template <int I, std::enable_if_t<!(I%2)>* = nullptr>
div() {
    std::cout << "I (" << I <<") am even." << std::endl;
}
```

As demonstrated here on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2f4d021f78bdf0c).